# Battery Drain, can't adjust brightness, overheating

Tags: 13.04, hp, battery, overheating

I have a HP pavillion DV7

Specs:

- Intel Core i7 @ 2.23 GHz (2nd. gen)
- 2 hard drives (500GB HDD, 160GB SSD)
- ATI Radeon HD XT 7

My PC is constantly overheating and my battery is drained in less than an hour. I am on Ubuntu 13.04. I already calibrated my battery for two nights.

Anyone having the same problem or anyone knows a solution?

I'm also having a problem with my brightness, I can't adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Could you run `top` on the terminal? If I can't help you, that will make the diagnosis easier for other people.

The top command will show every process running on the system. If I'm right there should be a process called "kworker/X:X" where X is some number, and it's consuming way more that it should (like 70% or something like that). This problem will have your CPU running all the time consuming lots of energy. Sadly this problem is not an Ubuntu bug, it's a Linux core bug. I have found a temporary solution for this. Just run `sudo reboot` when the kworker process apears, this will reboot your system and (at least in my case) solve the problem until you shutdown or reset your computer

If I'm not right, post the top result anyway, it will help a lot to find out what's your problem.

Comment: I can't post my hole top but there is no kworker/.. : .. that uses that much of my CPU. The thing that uses most is Xorg and it uses 5% of my .

Comment: How long does your battery last usually?

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the command `sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup`
2. Run the command `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
3. Make sure you do not see noacpi (set it to acpi or delete it, depending on where it is), pci=noacpi (set it to pci=acpi), or acpi=off (set it to acpi=on)
4. Reboot and see if it helps.

Basically, you set Ubuntu to use acpi to control the hardware, which generally fixes overheating. If your computer does not boot, revert /etc/default/grub to /etc/default/grub.backup.

Comment: i do not see this

Comment: Are you using Wubi?